# how to refer to beginning/middle/end in Mandarin?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm taking private Mandarin classes in Taipei. I'm having trouble referring to the beginning/middle/end of things. I asked my teacher how to say this, and the more I explained the more confused she got. Is this a cultural difference?

After some discussion, this basically seems to be a strange idea to communicate to her. But I'm having a hard time accepting this.

For example I asked how to say "the beginning of the week was rainy" She offered something involving me as the subject: 我剛開始 (wǒ gāng kāi shǐ
)... I explained It doesn't have anything to do with me. So now I'm more confused as I look over my notes. For whatever reason, it appears that referring to the beginning/middle/end of things requires a verb in Mandarin? I can accept this if I have to, but could someone help me put the following ideas into Mandarin:

```
the beginning/middle/end of the week (was hot)
the beginning/middle/end of the book (was exciting)
the beginning/middle/end of the summer (is when students arrive)
the beginning/middle/end of the year (seemed promising)
the beginning/middle/end of the speech (was inaudible)
the beginning/middle/end of the word ....
the beginning/middle/end of the hour
the beginning/middle/end of the movie
```

Thanks!!

Comment: How about using 初, 中 and 尽头 to describe the phenomena you are asking about? There are also special words relating to your question, like 初旬, 上旬, 中旬 and 下旬.

Comment: 初段（time），中段，尾段（space），末段（time）

Answer (score 3):

By "the beginning/middle/end", commonly Chinese words 初，开头，开始 /中，中间 /末，末尾，结尾 are related to them.

- **the beginning  /      middle     /end of the week (was hot)** 
  `一周初，一周开始/ ? 一周中间(几天) /周末............In Chinese, there's not an commonly used expression for middle of a weekend. we don't say it much.`
- **the beginning/middle/end of the book (was exciting)** 
  `书的开头      /中间  /末尾，结尾`
- **the beginning/middle/end of the summer (is when students arrive)**
  `夏初  /仲夏   /夏末.......... “仲夏” is relatively literary. We don't say “夏中” much, personally I've never seen it before.`
- **the beginning/middle/end of the year (seemed promising)**
  `年初      /年中   /年末，年尾，年终..........As “年中” and “年终” share the same pronunciation <niɑ̄n zhōng>, make it clear if you use them in daily oral expression.`
- **the beginning/middle/end of the speech (was inaudible)**
  `演讲开始   /中间  /末尾，结尾`
- **the beginning/middle/end of the word ....**
  `as above`
- **the beginning/middle/end of the movie**
  `as above`
- **the beginning/middle           /end of the hour**
  `一小时开头     /半小时(eg. 3:30) / ？  .......We don't directly say "end of an hour" much in Chinese, but this: when you wanna say end of an hour like 4:50, just say “快5点” or “接近5点” or “将近5点”`

Hope above helps. BTW, it may not be the same as your teacher told you, while I speak Mandarin of mainland China, there's few tiny differences of the language between Mainland and Taiwan, but feel free.